# Points from CSV file are not visible in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I am new to QGIS.
I have a CSV file with the coordinates of nursing homes in France. I would like to make them appear on QGIS, but it does not happen. Do you know where my error is?
[image]

And when I do that, QGIS is completely blank... It does not even recognize my nursing homes as points... (d0 is the same file as nursing_homes).

[image: not_displayed]

Comment: Try to uncheck 'coordonnées DMS' ...

Comment: No, they are not in Lambert projection (well only 2 points). They are in WG84 (I do not know which one, but in WGS84)

Comment: May you please share the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Deactivate the "DMS" When you import the points.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @snaileater said, I had to uncheck 'coordonnées DMS'.